# Getting error in minimax algorithm implementation for tictactoe - AutoLISP

Tags: algorithm, lisp, tic-tac-toe, minimax, autolisp

I wrote code that was supposed to calculate the best move for tic tac toe game, working on 1D array. "x" and "o" are values for players and "-" states that there's no move on this spot yet.

I'm getting error at some point and after hours trying to debug, I still have no idea why and where possibly I made mistake.

Error that I'm getting:
"error: bad function: 1"

I made prints in every single function, tried to put some breakpoints to localize where is the error coming from. For board = '("x" "o" "x" "o" "x" "o" "-" "-" "-") I could trace my code like so:

```
"minimax" 
"board=" (x o x o x o - - -)
"game-over" 
"win" 
"win" 
"full" 
"max-play" 
"repeat " 0
"repeat " 1
"repeat " 2
"repeat " 3
"repeat " 4
"repeat " 5
"repeat " 6
"minimax" 
"board=" (x o x o x o x - -)
"game-over" 
"win" 
"score" 
"win" 
"minimax" 
"board=" (x o x o x o x - -)
"game-over" 
"win" 
; error: bad function: 1
```

That helped me determine that every single time im getting this error (depends from starting board, once I got -1 instead 1) is coming from line 9:

```
(cond ((game-over board) (score board))
```

and apparently calling
 `(score board)`
causes it.

I've tried multiple possible solution but cant find error in my code. I would appreciate some help on finding mistake :/

I tried changing code multiple times but nothing helped

My code:

```
;;; function - minimax ----------------------------
(defun minimax (board player)
;;;  (setq gameover (game-over board))
;;;  (setq board2 board)
;;;  (setq score1 (score board))
;;;  (print "minimax: game-over=") (princ gameover) (princ ", board=") (princ board) (princ ", score=") (princ score1) (print)
  (print "minimax")
  (print "board=") (princ board)
  (cond ((game-over board) (score board))
        ((= player "x") (max-play board))
        (t (min-play board)));_cond
  )



;;; function - changeVal ----------------------------
(defun changeVal (list n val)
  (if (> n 0)
      (cons (car list)
            (changeVal (cdr list) (1- n) val))
    (if (= n 0)
        (cons val (cdr list))
      list)))


;;; function - max-play ----------------------------
;;;determine the best move for the 'X' player (the maximizing player) on the current game board state
(defun max-play (board)
  (print "max-play")
  (setq best-score -10)
  (setq best-move nil)
  (setq i 0)
  (repeat 9
    (print "repeat ") (princ i)
    (while (= (nth i board) "-")
      (setq new-board (changeVal board i "x"))
      (setq score (minimax new-board "o"))
      (setq new-board (changeVal board i "-"))
      (if (> score best-score)
    (setq best-score score)
    (setq best-move i)
    )
      );_while
    (setq i (+ i 1))
    );_repeat
  best-move
  )


;;; function - min-play ----------------------------
;;;determine the best move for the 'O' player (the minimizing player) on the current game board state
(defun min-play (board)
  (print "min-play")
  (setq best-score 10)
  (setq best-move nil)
  (setq i 0)
  (repeat 9
    (while (= (nth i board) "-")
      (setq new-board (changeVal board i "o"))
      (setq score (minimax new-board "x"))
      (setq new-board (changeVal board i "-"))
      (if (< score best-score)
          (setq best-score score)
          (setq best-move i)
    )
      );_while
    (setq i (+ i 1))
    );_repeat
  best-move
  )


;;; function - game-over ----------------------------
;;;check if the game has ended (win/draw) on the current game board state
(defun game-over (board)
  (print "game-over")
  (or (win board "x") (win board "o") (full board))
  )


;;;function - win ----------------------------
;;;check if a player has won the game on the current game board state
(defun win (board player)
  (print "win")
  ; check for horizontal, vertical, and diagonal wins
  (or ; horizontal wins
      (and (= (nth 0 board) player) (= (nth 1 board) player) (= (nth 2 board) player))
      (and (= (nth 3 board) player) (= (nth 4 board) player) (= (nth 5 board) player))
      (and (= (nth 6 board) player) (= (nth 7 board) player) (= (nth 8 board) player))
      ; vertical wins
      (and (= (nth 0 board) player) (= (nth 3 board) player) (= (nth 6 board) player))
      (and (= (nth 1 board) player) (= (nth 4 board) player) (= (nth 7 board) player))
      (and (= (nth 2 board) player) (= (nth 5 board) player) (= (nth 8 board) player))
      ; diagonal wins
      (and (= (nth 0 board) player) (= (nth 4 board) player) (= (nth 8 board) player))
      (and (= (nth 2 board) player) (= (nth 4 board) player) (= (nth 6 board) player)))
  )


;;; funkcja - full ----------------------------
;;;check if the game board is full (no more empty cells left)
(defun full (board)
  (print "full")
  (not (member "-" board))
  )

;;; funkcja - score ----------------------------
;;;checks if the game has ended in a win for 'X' player, 'O' player or a draw 
(defun score (board)
  (print "score")
  ; returns 1 if X wins, -1 if O wins, and 0 if it's a tie
  (cond ((win board "x") 1)
        ((win board "o") -1)
        (T 0))
  )

;;;;;; start
;;;(setq board '("x" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"))
(setq board '("x" "o" "x" "o" "x" "o" "-" "-" "-"))
;;;(setq board '("x" "x" "o" "x" "o" "x" "-" "-" "-"))
(setq minimaxOdp (minimax board "x"))
;;;(setq scoree (score '("x" "x" "o" "x" "o" "x" "o" "-" "-")))
;;;(setq board '("o" "x" "x" "o" "x" "-" "o" "-" "-"))
```

Comment: Posting a comment since I'm not intimately familiar with Autolisp's scoping rules, but having both `(setq score ...)` where `...` is likely to evaluate to ±1 and also a function named `score` seems sus.

Comment: I would seriously recommend using a standalone Lisp for learning Lisp, and using AutoLisp for extending and customizing AutoCAD.

Comment: You need local variables in your recursion. `setq` does not bind local variables; it is an assignment operator. AutoLisp isn't Python.